# How to handle 3D gmailQuote style design in my web application

Tags: asp.net

i am sending mails to otherdomains using my own server .in my domain the reply  messesages design is looking good.

but when i got reply from gmails why design is not coming properly in my application. i debug my application in that i saw 
`<div class="3D gmailQuote">` when got reply from gmail.that style i didn't write in my app.but when i got reply from 
gmails that style is coming .i think due to that in my app design of  the reply message looking ugly.

How to acheive this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your question clearly